# Error Calling Webservice Method Using SOAP

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, php-5.3

I'm a noobie when it comes to SOAP.  I am trying to make a SOAP request.  It works until I get to a specific method, and then fails with the following message:  **SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'transactionIdIn' property**

Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

//Set up client; username and password replaced for security
try  {
$client = new SoapClient('https://services.omnitracs.com/otsWebWS/services/OTSWebSvcs/wsdl/OTSWebSvcs.wsdl', 
                array('Username'=> {username},
                      'Password' => {password}));
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


//Call dequeue2 method
try  {
    $result = $client->dequeue2(array('subscriberId'=> "1", 'transactionId' => "0"));
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the wsdl I am calling:  https://services.omnitracs.com/otsWebWS/services/OTSWebSvcs/wsdl/OTSWebSvcs.wsdl

Here are the relevant parts of the wsdl that I am looking at:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://websvcs.otswebws">
    <wsdl:types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://websvcs.otswebws">
    <import namespace="http://datatype.otswebws"/>
    <element name="dequeueResponse">...</element>
    <element name="getSubscriberInfo">...</element>
    <element name="getSubscriberInfoResponse">...</element>
    <element name="dequeue2">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="subscriberId" type="xsd:int"/>
                <element name="transactionIdIn" type="xsd:long"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

<wsdl:portType name="OTSWebSvcs">
  <wsdl:operation name="dequeue">...</wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="getSubscriberInfo">...</wsdl:operation>
  <wsdl:operation name="dequeue2">
    <wsdl:input message="impl:dequeue2Request" name="dequeue2Request"></wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output message="impl:dequeue2Response" name="dequeue2Response"></wsdl:output>
    <wsdl:fault message="impl:WSException" name="WSException"></wsdl:fault>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

So, I guess I am not understanding the way the webservice is set up.  From what I understand, this OTSWebSvcs webservice has a dequeue2 method, which accepts two parameters, subscriberId and transactionIdIn.  Clearly, I am missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a typo in your script here:

```
$result = $client->dequeue2(array('subscriberId'=> "1", 'transactionId' => "0"));
```

It should be :

```
$result = $client->dequeue2(array('subscriberId'=> "1", 'transactionIdIn' => "0"));
```

as the soap Error tells you. Try it and let me know if it works for you now :-)

Comment: Yup, that worked.  I came here to close the question because I just noticed myself.  Thanks!